# Unjustified "variable is possibly null" warning in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-inspection

I like all the inspections in WebStorm, which help me clean up my code and find potential issues. But I fail to understand some warnings and they are getting into my way.

For example in the screenshot below you can see that I explicitly check if the variable `result` is `null`, and if so, assign an empty array to it. However, just below that WebStorm gives me a warning that the variable `result` is possibly null.

[image]

What is going on here? Do I have to clear a cache or is this simply a bug in WebStorm's inspections? Or am I missing something completely and the Warning is justified?

*Edit:* If this is a bug, it might be helpful to know that the variable is explicitly set to `null` on declaration (`let result = null;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitted to developers, please vote for [WEB-48756](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48756) to be notified on any progress with it